# How to connect to impala in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, impala

I want to build a model in PySpark. And input to this model form impala.Is it possible to connect from PySpark? Thanks!

Comment: Would you care elaborating and also providing with what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @eliasah I've only been tried to use the input from hive.That's easy.but impala,I have not idea.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to run Impala commands via a Shell script. And you can easily execute the shell script from pyspark via 'subprocess'.